How to draw amorphous but neat figures in Latex?
I would like to draw the following style of figures with Latex: (image found here)

The features I like about this drawing are the amorphous and skewed geometries (contrasted to my usual straight, rigid circles, rectangles, and cylinders), flat colour palette, and clean, thin lines. Is there any way to draw something like this? Is it too time consuming?

Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

The answer to "How" is "So", as a procedure. I highlighted relevant Tikz keywords, so you can look them up in the Tikz manual.
How to draw said sphere

\draw circle or \arc, filled with gray
draw an ellipse (\arc) as dashed line
put a simple shape for the dark area first, like a rectangle
replace by a polygon (i.e. a \draw ending in -- cycle;)
use rounded corners or bend or to[in=,out=] syntax
put a \node to have text ua (and one for E3)

How to draw the lower plane

reuse abov's polygon approach
fill with lighter gray
draw ellipse with option draw=none to avoid the line
place two \nodes for the text

How to draw the arrow

reuse above's approach:
draw a line, dashed
use bend or to syntax
place a node at midways position for the \psi
add \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} to your preamble
use e.g. {Stealth} for the arrow tip

Is it time consuming?
For a novice, perhaps.
But it's like in the gym: do it and grow in strength quickly.

P.S.: Feel free to add your coding attempts from this procedure to your question. It will always be easier to help you overcome concrete hurdles. Wishing you success

thank you!!! I can't upvote you yet :/

Fine + no problem. // Many Tikz diagrams will use what I described. So once you mastered these tools, you can do many diagrams.
